# IntelliJ, disable cursor moving after commenting a line with a shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I comment out or in a line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in IntelliJ 14 the cursor moves a line down.
How can I disable that?

Comment: I don't believe that's something that's end-user configurable.

Comment: I've test in my IntelliJ 14, so, Ctrl + Shift + / would comment out the code selection.

Comment: The point in this question is that I don't want the cursor AFTER comment in or out a line to move.

Comment: I would offer to expand answers of sina72, Martin Kloski and especially user14126989. You can 1. select cursor let, 2. select ciursor right 3. dance a short dance 4. drink a coffee 5. use the macros 6. right-click the mouse and finally 7. put two characters of "//".... But really, thanks for the question! I'd go with the Macros since there is no simpler option... :(

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583108 points to exact setting which is responsible for this mechanism (no macros or workarounds needed).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot disable that, however you can define a macro.

1. Start with `Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to comment out current line
3. Press <kbd>Up</kbd> to move caret to that line again
4. End with `Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording`

The caret will return to the same logical position as before, just as expected.

You can assign that macro to any keyboard shortcut you like: `Settings | Keymap | Macros`

Comment: There's an unfortunate problem with this: the cursor movement after commenting is language dependent. When editing Java, the cursor moves to the next line after commenting; when editing XML, the cursor does not move. Setting this macro "fixes" the behavior for Java but then breaks the behavior for XML. I have found no way to make it work properly in both contexts.

Comment: Also, macro execution isn't instantaneous, so you can see the cursor jump down and up.

Answer (score 17):

The solution mentioned by [Dmitry Batrak on the YouTrack forum](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283756#focus=Comments-27-5579465.0-0) worked for me.

Go to *Settings* > *Advanced Settings*. In the *Editor* section, deselect "Move caret down after Comment with Line Comment action".

The macro method in the accepted answer is not required anymore.

Comment: Works as of PyCharm 2023.1

Comment: I guess it works on all IntelliJ based IDEs; tried it on Android Studio too

Answer (score 10):

workaround with no macros:  if you select the line or a single character from the line, and then comment out, the caret will stay at same position.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better result (imo) can be obtained by combining the macro approach with `Markin Klosi`'s answer (an other of `sina72`'s answer is that if you select some text and comment with the macro, the caret will now move UP a line).

So, follow `sina72`'s answer but record this macro:

1. select a character left (e.g. shift+left arrow)
2. comment the line
3. deselect the character (e.g. shift+right arrow)

[Example macro result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzVov.png)

---

ps: having to do this is less than ideal.
There are other cases where the caret jumps around without any valid reason (example: after "introduce local variable" in java it goes to EOL)