# How to stop moving one line down while commenting in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Whenever I comment (<kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd>) in PhpStorm, the IDE automatically moves the pointer one line down. How do I disable that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is possible you may find your answer in a previous question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407481/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-in-phpstorm-ide#:~:text=Select%20multiple%20lines%20and%20use,htaccess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. I mean: there is no option for that.

But you can try a workaround using Macro: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545802/783119 ... or make a selection (1 symbol anywhere in the line will be enough) before using the shortcut.

Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**P.S.** I personally like current behaviour: it allows me to quickly disable & enable subsequent lines (in any supported language/file format that has line comments) without making any selection.